# Main(string[] args) method not called

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Whenever I press `F5` to start debugging my program, I notice that the `Main(string[] args)` method inside the `Program` class is not called, even though the fields inside `Program` are initialized, as you can see from the screenshot below:

[image]

After creating a `TcpClient` instance and then assigning it to the corresponding field, the debugger never hits the breakpoint I have set on the `Main(string[] args)` method.

Just to be sure, I have set the startup object for my project to be the `Program` class. That did not fix the issue:

[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have added `Console.WriteLine("Entering Main method...")` inside my `Main` method, but it is not printed to the console when I start debugging.

Literally nothing (or rather, nothing immediately visible) happens after the `TcpClient` instance is created -- no exceptions thrown; the program doesn't self-terminate; the console stays blank.

**EDIT:**

Turns out a crash is occurring inside the `TcpClient` constructor.

Comment: Maybe it's failing before?

Comment: So what *does* happen? Does the code immediately crash (e.g. in that construtor call)? What happens if you run it from the command line instead?

Comment: Also, try putting a `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` or something like that into the Main method and see if it prints

Comment: @KeithPaulBarrow no - it seems to work if it's private as well.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the constructor of `TcpClient` is completing? If you move the assignment and constructor call into `Main` (with "before" and "after" diagnostic output) what happens? Is anything actually listening on that host/port?

Comment: The code you show is a static initializer. It will always run *before* `Main()` or any other static method is called

Comment: I think something is wrong with the initialization of TcpClient. Try comment it out and see what happens. Process seems to be locked somehow...

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right that there is a crash inside the ``TcpClient`` constructor. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the `TcpClient(string, int)` constructor opens a new connection, at that point ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_String_System_Int32_)):

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and connects to the specified port on the specified host.
>   ...
>   This constructor creates a new TcpClient and makes a synchronous connection attempt to the provided host name and port number.

If I copy/paste your code (inserting my own `RemoteServerIpAddressString`), then I see the application hang as it tries to construct the `TcpClient`. If I break the debugger at that point, I can see that it's stuck in `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect`, which is trying to connect to the remote machine.

After a while it gives up, throws an exception, and a `TypeInitializationException` gets thrown, which breaks the debugger.

This matches your observation:

> Literally nothing (or rather, nothing immediately visible) happens after the TcpClient instance is created -- no exceptions thrown; the program doesn't self-terminate; the console stays blank.

At this point, the `TcpClient` is still trying to connect. Until it succeeds, the type never gets initialized, and until this happens `Main` will never be run. If you leave it long enough it will probably fail, just as mine did.

If I make sure that the `TcpClient` is connecting to a port which is open, then the `TcpClient` constructor completes straight away and `Main` runs.

---

It's a very bad idea to do long-running things - especially network-y things - inside a static constructor. The CLR needs to acquire a lock when a type is being initialized, and this stops other types from being initialized, and can cause deadlocks.

You probably want to either construct the `TcpClient` inside your `Main` method, or construct it as:

```
private static readonly TcpClient TcpClient = new TcpClient();
```

and then in main:

```
TcpClient.Connect(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Static field initializers *in this case (the Program class)* shouldn't contain code that may throw or time out.

The code highlited in the question is a static field initializer. This will run the first time a type is accessed, [before any static method or even the static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-field-initialization). If the initializers or the static constructor block or throw, the application will terminated without calling `Main`. This means that no error handling code can be used to catch those exceptions.

This guaranteed order makes implementing simple singletons in C# *very* easy. No double locking is needed as the order of execution is guaranteed. Check Jon Skeet's article on [Singleton implementation](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton) :

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()    {    }
    private Singleton()   {    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

That's enough to create a thread-safe singleton

Comment: @canton7 oops. It's in the [spec too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-field-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a new answer because I hit a similar issue in a more complex hosting environment that was hiding class load and other initialization exceptions.

In order to catch the issue, I did this:

- Renamed my `Main` method to `Main2`, so it does not conflict with the next change.
- Created another Program class, clean this time, that calls `Main2`, like the one below:

```
class CleanProgram {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            Program.Main2(args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**The change above is only for diagnostics purposes!** After you find and fix the problem, the change can be undone.